# Show price with decimals but keeping the 0 (Prestashop)

Tags: prestashop

I get the price in a .php file with the code:

```
Tools::ps_round((string)$prod->getPriceWithoutReduct(), 2);
```

and I get for example: **59.4** but I need **59.40** how can I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use plain PHP !

```
number_format(Tools::ps_round((string)$prod->getPriceWithoutReduct(), 2), 2);
```